# dc.js - is it possible to show the user grab handles upon page load

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I'm building a basic dashboard for internal use. I've little experience with D3 / SVG etc so please excuse me if this is obvious:

#### Aim

I have a time series of values, one value per date for a full year. Inspired by the example on the [dc.js wesbite](http://nickqizhu.github.io/dc.js/), I'm displaying a 'mini' bar plot of the entire series, and allowing the user to select a range which in turn sets the limits of the axis scale range of a 'large' line plot.

By default (on page load / refreshAll()) I've set the limits of the large line plot to be the most recent 60 days.

The user is encouraged to set their desired range using the mini plot at the bottom, and when they do, the 'grab handles' appear and the chosen range is highlighted on the mini plot, for example:

[image: grab_handles_shown]

#### My issue

On page load / refreshAll(), the grab handles and range highlighting aren't shown on the mini plot, for example:

[image: no_grab_handles]

#### Question

Is there a way I can set the grab handles to appear upon page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how i do it by using crossfilter and dc.js. You can get the last x days by doing something like:

```
xrange = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; });
last60 = [d3.time.day.offset(xrange[1], -60), d3.time.day.offset(xrange[1], 1)]
```

Assuming you have a `date` in your data. Do this after reading the data with d3, but before feeding it into crossfilter.

Then for the bottom chart (mini plot) simply set the filter property to:

```
.filter(last60)
```

And also set the xrange for the top chart to the same range:

```
.x(d3.time.scale().domain(last60))
```

Something like this might also work for setting the xrange, but i havent had any success with that:

```
topchart.focus(bottomchart.filter())
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this - I was headed down almost exactly the same path, only I was not correctly casting the filter dates as dates - I had them as unix timestamps. I'll mark as correct answer for now, but I have an issue with adding .filter() which throws an error in dc.js. I'm just creating a jsFiddle now to demonstrate that you solution works for me :)

Comment: I'll have a look at the Fiddle. I populate my `date` by parsing string with `dateFormat = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");` and then within a `data.forEach(` loop use `d.date = dateFormat.parse(d.date)`, i hope that makes sense. You might try setting a manual date to see if the error still occurs by using `.filter([new Date(2013, 1, 15), new Date(2013, 4, 26)])`, setting the xUnits to days might also be necessary: `.xUnits(d3.time.days)`.

Comment: I've knocked together this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonsedar/mAFtB/) which demonstrates your answer working - thank you very kindly!

Comment: Here is my fork adding some elements from my implementation: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RutgerK/prHZD/1/). The `renderlet` and `on("filtered"` are needed to link both charts. I also prefer to round the bars to days to make the brush snap, so you cant select half a bar. Somehow i only get this to work with `.centerBar(false)`.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, it seems that this very functionality has been changed in dc.js 1.4.0, see my [forked JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonsedar/e6QZT/) for more details. I think I'll send this to the [dc.js usergroup](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/dc-js-user-group) since I'd like to use v1.4.0 and it seems to have broken functionality. Cheers!

Comment: Phew. The latest issue was caused by dc.js 1.4.0 having a dependency on crossfilter v1.2.0. For what it's worth I've updated my final fork on jsFiddle.