# dc.js - How set brush (with specific width) to barChart on load

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, dc.js

On load i see this, all data set without filters:
[Picture: what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6tCg.png)

I want to see this, brush(selector) picked last 21 day already on load:
[Picture: what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9GXi.png)
[Solved! click for answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897568/dc-js-how-set-brush-with-specific-width-to-barchart-on-load#comment61389921_36897568)

Here i saw similar question, but not works for me
[dc.js - is it possible to show the user grab handles upon page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17281653/dc-js-is-it-possible-to-show-the-user-grab-handles-upon-page-load)

```
var lineChart = dc.lineChart(".chart-line-graph");
var dateRangeChart = dc.barChart('.chart-date-range');

var hourDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.hour;});
var valueByHour = hourDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.value;});
var minDate = hourDim.bottom(1)[0].date;
var maxDate = hourDim.top(1)[0].date;

lineChart
    .renderArea(true)
    .width(1360)
    .height(350)
    .transitionDuration(200)
    .margins({top: 30, right: 50, bottom: 45, left: 80})
    .dimension(hourDim)
    .mouseZoomable(true)
    .rangeChart(dateRangeChart)
    .brushOn(false)
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate]))
    .elasticY(true)
    .group(value)
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true);

var dayDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {return d.day;});
var groupByDayDim = moveDays.group();

dateRangeChart
    .width(1360)
    .height(35)
    .margins({top: 0, right: 50, bottom: 20, left: 80})
    .dimension(moveDays)
    .group(volumeByMonthGroup)
    .centerBar(false)
    .gap(1)
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate]))
    .round(d3.time.week.round)
    .alwaysUseRounding(true)
    .xUnits(d3.time.days);
dateRangeChart
    .yAxis().ticks(0);
```

If i add this:

```
lineChart
    .filter(dc.filters.RangedFilter(d3.time.day.offset(xrange[1], -21), d3.time.day.offset(xrange[1], 1)))
```

Then barChart are filtered, but not selected

Comment: Does it help if you call a dc.redrawAll() after applying the filter to the chart?

Comment: Nope( I guess, i need somethin like .focus() but dont know how impelent it correctly

Comment: Is the filter supposed to be on the daterangechart or the linechart? Any chance of a working example?

Answer (score 2):

I solved my first problem!
Just added filter after all code (after renderAll()) and then call redrawAll()

Screenshot, how it looks like for now, on load charts
[image: screenshot]